# Python: equivalent of os.walk for folders that are stored in a git repository

Tags: python, git, os.walk

Current code

```
myfolder = '../../../../../config'

for directory, subdirectories, files in os.walk(myfolder ):
```

myfolder used to be in the same git repo as this code.
But a refactoring lead to it being moved in another git repository

What's the best way for Python to access this folder?

I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: is that repo checked out in a known location?

Answer (score 0):

use `__file__` in case the relative path is stable

```
import pathlib

cur_file_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent 
external = cur_file_dir / '../../../../../config'
```